# Weird behaviour with Node.js exec and stdout

Tags: javascript, node.js, boolean, exec

I'm trying to convert String to Boolean from stdout.

Someone could explain me why this code return `false` instead `true`:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process')

exec('echo true', {}, (err, stdout) => {
    const current = stdout.toString();

    console.log(typeof current, current) // <- It returns: string true

    const status = (current === 'true');

    console.log(status); // <- I echoed true, I checked for true and instead I'm getting false
})
```

https://repl.it/@michelem09/WeirdStdout

Comment: Because of the trailing "newline" of course. `/true/.test(current)` would return `true`, or strip the newline.

Comment: oh crap! I didn't think about newline! Thanks

Comment: In case someone who don't understand what Neil is saying: to make it return "True" you need (current.trim() === 'true') instead of just (current === 'true'), because of the new line appended to "current".